# Why is Quantized Inertia considered pseude-science?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, inertia

In the criticism section of the Wikipedia article to Quantized Intertia it is stated that QI is considered pseudo-science. Unfortunately none of the linked but in none of the provided links can I find a solid critique of QI and why it should be considered pseudo-science.

While I lack the required to follow the math provided in Mike McCulloch's papers, the argument seems plausible. Since QI is - according to the Wikipedia article - not only considered a fringe theory but pseude-science, I must be missing.

What are the obvious flaws and problems that make QI pseudo-science?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436874/2451

Comment: I don't think that Physics SE should contain a bunch of questions along the lines of 'Why is Theory X not considered mainstream?', so there is that. Second, one might contemplate why, if you can't follow the math, you still find the argument plausible. Somewhere there is a disconnect there, from a physics perspective.

Comment: This review by an astrophysicist in a "popular" magazine (Forbes) has various criticisms of the theory: https://www.forbes.com/sites/briankoberlein/2017/02/15/quantized-inertia-dark-matter-the-emdrive-and-how-to-do-science-wrong/#4d911fd4675f

Comment: Quantised inertia is a *fringe* theory but clearly not in the same category as weird rants on personal websites: there are plenty of publications about it in mainstream physics journals (and it fits alongside other ways like modified Newtonian dynamics as a way of explaining galactic rotation without dark matter). So it isn't clear why discussion is being closed because it sits with "unpublished personal theories".